# Creating aggregated column in SQL with values depending on previous row - MySQL 5

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, mysql-python, mysql5

I would like to get some help on the following query:
I have the following data frame I created with python pandas:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'user_id':[1,1,1,2,2],'event':[1,0,1,1,0]})
```

The output is:

```
user_id event
 1      1
 1      0
 1      1
 2      1
 2      0
```

Now, I have created a third column in the following way: **for every user_id group**, if the previous value of event is 0, then write 1, else 0:

```
g = data.groupby('user_id')
data['third_column']=g['event_id'].transform(lambda x: np.where((x.shift(1)==0),1,0))
```

And I get

```
user_id event   third_column
 1      1       0
 1      0       0
 1      1       1
 2      1       0
 2      0       0
```

How can I reproduce the same output in MySQL 5?

Thanks for your help

Comment: "window functions" is what you are really looking for. Unfortunately, there is not too much support in MySQL 5.x though it is feasible by using variables and subselects. However, the main issue is that you need to specify some sort of ordering because there is no such concept as a "previous" record in the relational world. SQL deals with data_set_s. So first of all, you need to sort this out.

Comment: @GyőzőPapp thank for your comment. Sorry what do I need to sort out first?

Comment: so how would you define the term "previous"? If it was simply the order of "appearance" the records being inserted then you would need to add an extra column to your table (either a simple autoincrement or timestamp column would suffice) and use that column in an ORDER BY clause. Check out the ranking solution here https://dev.to/maxborysov/mysql-5-7-window-function-workaround-1h76 to get it how it works.